# What is the difference between auxiliary and modal verbs?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs, terminology

I'm badly confused between modal and auxiliary verbs. What are the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modals are a subclass of auxiliaries.  All modal verbs are also auxiliary verbs, but not all auxiliary verbs are modals.  The auxiliaries not conventionally included among the modals are *be*, *have* and *do* - all of which double up as full verbs.

The modals have various shared characteristics - they don't have a separate third-person singular ending and they don't have infinitives or participles.  *Be* and *have* have infinitives and participles, even when fulfilling their auxiliary functions (e.g. "to be seen", "to have seen"), which is one of the reasons for classifying them differently.

The modals are *can, may, will, shall, must, ought*.  The semi-modals are *need* and *dare* (which *do* have infinitives and participles), and arguably one or two others (depending which book you read).  (Also, *ought* is sometimes classed as semi-modal instead of modal, because of its particular characteristics.)

*Could, might, would, should* are sometimes listed as modals, although really they are the past-tense forms of *can, may, will, shall*, so don't need to be listed separately.